# How to get plain text from cookie in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, cookies

How to get value from cookie in Angularjs, cookieStore.get only accepts encoded text like %22sometext22%. 
if i make cookie like this ,its ok but i have cookies with plain text and then i cant get that value, any ideas?

Comment: Try the javascript [decodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent).

Answer (score 0):

try to use the [$cookies](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies) service instead of the $cookieStore service to manipulate your cookies as the last one is deprecated.

Comment: i have tried that and error was cookies.get is not a function                          but i found this, will it work?  var favoriteCookie = $cookies[user_id];

Comment: Have you injected ngCookies in your angular module ? you have to call it `$cookie.get("nameOfTheCookieVariable")`

Answer (score 0):

ok i found out how to get that properly

var cookieValue = $cookies["cookieName"];